# Blazor WebApp Client Unable to resolve service for type IAccessTokenProvider

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a new WebApp project that has been configured to authenticate using the Duende demo API. I have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-8.0#attach-tokens-to-outgoing-requests) for using a custom AuthorizationMessageHandler for passing tokens to the API. My goal here was to create a dirt simple example of using the new WebApp template that connects to an OIDC provider.

The referenced documentation states "AuthorizationMessageHandler is a DelegatingHandler used to process access tokens. Tokens are acquired using the IAccessTokenProvider service, **which is registered by the framework**.".

When I run the project and browse to the page that calls the API I get the error "No service for type IAccessTokenProvider has been registered".

Here is the sample project: https://github.com/mohaaron/CustomAuthorizationHandler/

Steps to reproduce:
Pull Github repo
Run WebApp project
Login to the demo identity server
Navigate to the Fetch Remote Data menu item

I hope I'm just tired and missing something simple.

Comment: .net8 has built-in jwt token authentication.

Comment: @QiangFu how does this resolve my question?